# Android Background/Cached Process

Tags: android, process

Currently with my app if I press the home button, the app disappears and the audio is still playing. Which is want I want it to do.
However when I go to Manage Applications and check my running apps, it is only visible when I select show cached/background processes.

In order to make it a running process, do I need to create a service, is that the ONLY way? Is there another way?
And if so would this affect performance and how?

I have searched other posts on stackoverflow, but they haven't given me a direct answer to my questions.

Comment: If your app is doing few seconds task then you can do it in AsyncTask, otherwise service is the only way.

Comment: Yes you need to use `Service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to make it a running process, do I need to create a service, is that the ONLY way?

You can chop off the user's arms to prevent the user from pressing HOME, BACK, etc., so that your app is always in the foreground. Not only will this keep the process in the running list, but the user will be unable to get to Settings in the first place. Note that this technique may be illegal in some jurisdictions.

Otherwise, yes, you need to create a service.

The "cached/background" processes means that your process will vanish sometime soon, when the OS needs RAM and your process is the most likely one to terminate to free up RAM.

> And if so would this affect performance and how?

It will make your app more likely to be left alone longer. This makes it more likely that other apps will be kicked out of memory, harming the user's ability to multitask.

Otherwise, there is no real effect on most metrics of "performance".